# OpenMPI: MPI_Send allocates more and more memory

Tags: c++, memory, mpi, send, openmpi

I'm currently working on a code which crashes after some time during a MPI communication due to running out of memory. I was wondering why the code uses more and more memory since I tried to reduce the allocations as much as possible. A college of mine has a similar problem with his code.

So I found that this seems to be caused by my send and recv routine and therefore I wrote an example which shows a similar behavior (in a smaller scale):

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <iomanip>

rusage mem_usage;
int mem_proc;
int mem_max;
int mem_min;
int mem_sum;
int mem_sum_old;
double mem_avg;

int world_size;
int world_rank;


void PrintMemUsage(std::string prefix)
{
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    getrusage( RUSAGE_SELF, &mem_usage);

    mem_proc = mem_usage.ru_maxrss;

    MPI_Allreduce(&mem_proc,&mem_sum,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Allreduce(&mem_proc,&mem_min,1,MPI_INT,MPI_MIN,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Allreduce(&mem_proc,&mem_max,1,MPI_INT,MPI_MAX,MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    mem_avg = ((double) mem_sum) / ((double) world_size);

    if(mem_sum_old == 0)
        mem_sum_old = mem_sum;

    if(world_rank == 0) std::cout << "("<< world_rank << ") " << std::setw(50) << std::left << prefix << " MEM: " << mem_sum << " KB.  MIN: " << mem_min << " MAX: " << mem_max << " AVG: " << mem_avg << " Change: " << (mem_sum)-(mem_sum_old) << " KB" << std::endl;
    mem_sum_old = mem_sum;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    double send = 42.0;
    double recv = 1;
    int i;
    MPI_Request Request[2];

    PrintMemUsage("start");

    for(i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        MPI_Send (&send, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, (world_rank+1)%world_size, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv (&recv, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, (world_rank-1)%world_size, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);           
    }

    PrintMemUsage("end");

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Running this code with 2 cores leads to the following output:

```
mpirun -np 2 ./test
(0) start                                              MEM: 53068 KB.  MIN: 26528 MAX: 26540 AVG: 26534 Change: 0 KB
(0) end                                                MEM: 53300 KB.  MIN: 26632 MAX: 26668 AVG: 26650 Change: 232 KB
```

The needed memory rises with more cores involved. Therefore it seems like the send and recv functions allocates more and more memory. Putting the output into the loop shows that the additional memory is not allocated once, it is allocated several times (but not always).

I have tested this with several MPI and GCC versions for example with gcc 4.9.2 and MPI 1.8.3 the amount of needed additional memory seems to vary with the chosen version.

Does someone know why this is happening and especially how I can work around this?

Thank you very much for your help and best wishes

Klaus

Comment: There are multiple dynamically-sized buffers maintained by the library. There are *far too many* parameters that can be used to tweak the size of those buffers (`ompi_info --all | grep buffer` for a quick taste) and I would **not** recommend that you change their values. Unless the RSS delta keeps raising linearly with the number of send/receives and doesn't seem to hit some limit, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: I second the advice from @HristoIliev. If you don't use buffered communication, you're already in the "least amounts of buffers" area ;). Trying to improve the default behaviour of your MPI implementation is really hard to do and seldom does anything for the better.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried to use MPI_Ibsend to set the buffer myself, but this seemed not to change anything. The problem is, that at some point my program is running out of memory and thus it crashs. I could somehow save all intermediate stages and then rerun the program, but I would prefer if the program finishs without such problems...

Comment: One of the very many ways to run out of memory that additionally suggests that MPI is to blame is just to have `MPI_*Sends` that are not matched by enough `MPI_*Receives`. Somewhere the data will **have** to be buffered. If you used `MPI_I*Send` and `MPI_I*Receive` you could control the memory yourself and maybe avoid allocations at all. Tools like Intel Trace Analyzer can point you to unmatched sends.

Comment: That does not work for `world_rank==0`:
`(world_rank-1)%world_size`
you have to add `world_size`.

Comment: The code as it is might deadlock as it can just wait for the `MPI_Send()` to complete while the matching `MPI_Recv()` aren't posted. So you rely implicitly on internal buffering (which saves you) but complain that is uses memory... Just fix your code by using `MPI_Irevc()` then `MPI_Ssend()` or `MPI_Issend()` and `MPI_Waitall()`. That should both improve performance and avoid buffering.

Comment: Or just use `MPI_Sendrecv` if you don't want to manually meddle with non-blocking operations.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sendrecv is Not possible since the Problem also takes place in a larger Code where i can not use blocking communication. I also tried to set the buffer myself and use ibsend but this does not seem to change anything

Comment: Did you notice that I proposed to 1/ post receiving calls **before** sending calls to avoid unexpected incoming messages (which are a pain to deal with internally and might increase the memory consumption); and 2/ to use **synchronous** sending to avoid (implicit) buffering? Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry Gilles missed answering you. Yes, I also tried it with first using Irecv and then Isend. It delivered the same result (my original code is set up like this). I havent tried synchron sending, I will test it (unfortunately I do not have a PC avaible at the moment)

Comment: I now also tried synchronous sending and got again the same result.